# How to Use Child Window to search for textbox Content in Parent Window?

Tags: c#, winforms

Hi I am trying to Create a Notepad similar to windows notepad.
I am stuck in a situation where i want to find the text searched in Find box(like we have in notepad) and to show the selected text in the parent window which has a textbox with all the text.

I tried making the method static to access the Searched text in the parent window.
Here's the code for that :

```
 namespace NotePadApp
 {
public partial class Find : Form
{

    static string SearchText="";
    static Find Findbox;

 static Find Findbox;


    public static string GetSearchText()
    {
        Findbox = new Find();
        Findbox.ShowDialog();
        return SearchText;

    }

  }}
```

I am able to access the static method GetSearchText().

But Only when i close the Find(child) window that text is searched.

So i want to make the child window opened with user searching for text using that window for the content in parent window.

Comment: why not give that form the textbox in a ctor? or set it to a field after instantiating it before calling the show dialog? or I misunderstood you?

Comment: i want the search to be reflected on the textbox in the parentwindow by the textbox in childwindow. Just like the windows notepad. So passing the Constructor wont reflect that real time change on the current instance of the parent window i suppose or am i wrong ? I am trying parent child relationship let me see if that works by passing the current instance of parent to child.

Comment: "But Only when i close the Find(child) window that text is searched."  Use **Show()** instead of ShowDialog() then.  As @James pointed out, you need a reference to the "parent" form as well so you can work with it.

Comment: Thanks a lot Idle_Mind.. Few days back i saw one Stack question and that was also cause of show() and ShowDialog() difference. But when it was time to use that knowledge i sucked big time. U made my day :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have the content control (Textbox or whatever) in the main window wrapped in a public property if you are trying to just read or write to the control or have a public method if you need to do something else. You can have a public method on the main form that takes the search criteria as a parameter for example.

You can access the main form using `Application.OpenForms` from the find form.

Say for example `Form1` is your main form and you give it a public property called `MyTextArea`

On your find form you can do this

```
var mainForm = (Form1)Application.OpenForms["Form1"];
```

You can then access the control on your main form with

```
mainForm.MyTextArea ....
```

Comment: Do you need help on the actual method for selecting the text rather than controlling the parent form?

Comment: I used your technique to get the relation done and in the end idle_mind let me reach the finish line.

Comment: Nice One. Good you got it sorted

Answer (score 0):

Making things static is rarely the right way to go about things. You need to think about *getting the find box result* as a *method* that displays a form and returns a result to the parent window.

Give the "FindBox" dialog some public properties (`FindText` and/or `ReplaceText`, for example) to store the user's input(s) (you could set them when the user clicks the "Ok" button, like `FindText = findTextBox.Text`), and write a method that the parent form can access:

```
DialogResult FindTextInEditor(out string findText)
{
    // instantiate the FindForm and display it with .ShowDialog()
    var findForm = new FindBox();
    var result = findForm.ShowDialog();

    // set the out parameter using the public properties of the FindBox:
    findText = findForm.FindText;

    // if the user cancelled out the caller needs to know:
    return result;
}
```

The parent/main form just needs to call this method to display the "find box" and get the results back - could look something like this:

```
string findText;
var result = FindTextInEditor(out findText);

if (result != DialogResult.Cancel)
{
    // search the text editor content for "findText"
}
```

Comment: Hi the method u mentioned is really good. but how to pass the information with out closing the Child form. below are the scenarios where i am struggling :1. When user clicks on Find Text in Find(child) form then the text should be selected in the parent window. 2. Focus should get back to parent. 3. if user again tries to search same thing should happen (1 & 2 ) 4. User can close the find window and focus should get back to parent window. Just like notepad .